# Django permission advice

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

I am at a crossroad actually in my Django 1.5 project and need some community advice before turning right or left.

Here are my models **Article Model**

```
class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name="Titre")
    zone = models.ForeignKey('Zone', verbose_name=u"Area")
```

and my **Zone Model**

```
   class Zone(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.name)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['name']
```

Each article is in a geographic "zone".

All my users depends also on the same "zone" and can edit/add/delete article that belong to the same "zone" as user does.

**Path #1 :**

I must work with django-guardian. It will pay on the long run or overkill ?

**Path #2 :**

I only need to set ForeignKey CustomUser Model <-> Zone Model <-> Article Model.
Then I check for each view if CustomUser.Zone == Article.Zone before proceeding.

**Path #3 :**

Your call.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the question ? What is django-guardian ?

Comment: django-guardian is a per object permission https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian tool. The question is "what would be your choice at this crossroad ?"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best is to create Proxy Model, modifying queryset in ModelAdmin and managing permission against that proxymodel.

http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2010/dec/16/using-proxy-models-customize-django-admin/